# Starting: Intent { cmp=com.reactnavigationv6/.MainActivity } problem

Tags: android, react-native, npm, ionicons

My app was working just fine, I just added calendar icon and date picker to my code :

```
import React, {useState,  useContext}  from 'react';
import {View, Text,StyleSheet,ScrollView,TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  Platform,
  TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {AuthContext} from '../context/AuthContext';
import { BASE_URL } from '../utils/config';

import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';

import Constants from "expo-constants";
import CustomButton from '../components/CustomButton'
import axios from "axios";
```

and it worked fine but then i forgot what i did and the app doesn't work anymore and the emulator doesn't open my app.
this is the response when i run the app:

```
>react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:10340) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency      
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 2800 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'android29(AVD) - 10' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
154 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 150 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.reactnavigationv6/.MainActivity }
```

when i run react-native info, i have this response:

```
System:
        OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
        CPU: (12) x64 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400H @ 2.70GHz
        Memory: 1.91 GB / 15.71 GB
      Binaries:
        Node: 16.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE      
        Yarn: 1.22.18 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD        
        npm: 8.12.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
        Watchman: Not Found
      SDKs:
        Android SDK: Not Found
      IDEs:
        Android Studio: AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
      Languages:
        Java: 11.0.15
        Python: 3.9.11
      npmPackages:
        @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
        react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
        react-native: ^0.63.2 => 0.63.2
      npmGlobalPackages:
        *react-native*: Not Found
```

and when i try to install packages with npm i have this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: reactnavigationv6@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.13.1" from react-native@0.63.4    
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"^0.63.2" from the root project   
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli       
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/cli@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry   
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps 
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ghars\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:      
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ghars\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-22T17_29_53_171Z-debug-0.log
```

Can someone help me with this, please.

Comment: Have you tried running `npx react-native-clean-project` and deleting all the Android build caches? Also try uninstalling the app from the device and rebuilding.

Comment: It didn't work, here's the output after running android : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.

Comment: Do you have previously saved versions you can go back to (ie on Git or something similar)?  If you can go back to a version that works, you can check the differences in your current version.  Your new error message looks like you have a dependency that requires a higher compileSdkVersion - you could try changing that in build.gradle to what the error is suggesting.